# Layout on my page changes when maximizing the page, how is this stopped?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want all my information to be in the center as you can see in the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/EdHEu/

It looks fine BUT when i stretch/maximize the browser page the layout changes by text going right and then the boxes moving.

How is this stopped?

Thanks!

James

Comment: your link does point to your jsfiddle

Comment: You need to save that jsFiddle before you post a link to it.

Comment: sorry guys, there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/EdHEu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: Your Link is not working.

If your setup is like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <!--Sidebar-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

To Center the content ( to give the page a fixed width ), you need to use this CSS:

```
#main {
  width:960px /* Give it a width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* It will Center the #main */
}
```

This way, you can give the page a fixed width and make the layout fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at [**this code (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/josh_max/EdHEu/6/) & see if that cleans it up a bit more, too.

```
HTML:

<div class="content">
    <form class="location" action="weezyresults.php" method="post">

        <div>
            <label for="job">job?</label>
            <div class="input" name="job" >
                <!-- change me back to your inputs, 
                and in the css change '.input' to 'input' -->
            </div> 
            <label>job title or keywords</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="where">where?</label>
            <div class="input" name="where" >
                <!-- change me back to your inputs, 
                and in the css change '.input' to 'input' -->
            </div> 
            <label>town, city or county</label>
        </div>

    </form>
</div><!-- end .content -->


CSS:

.content {
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:200px;
}

form>div { margin-bottom: 10px; }

form .input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #BDBDBD;
    height:35px;
    margin:2px;
    width: 320px;
}


div>label:first-child {
    color: #585858;
    font: bold 16px helvetica;
    height:20px;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 320px;
}

div>label:last-child {
    color: #585858;
    font:italic 13px HelveticaNeue-Light;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 651px;
}
```